# What is cause of internet malfunction?

Tags: internet, 9.0-pie

When phone is brand new and updated to latest firmware and network is also good then what possible causes can be of internet malfunction?

I'm using Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2 
Running on stable pie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are potential causes of internet malfunction?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213319/what-are-potential-causes-of-internet-malfunction)

Comment: @irfan Latif this is my own unanswered question that I had forget I already asked.

Comment: It is a duplicate however nobody has answered it.

Comment: I have answered your previous question.